# Purpose of INT_MIN

Tags: c++

I was solving a question in hackerrank on 2D array, this is an hourglass program where we have to find  sum for every hourglass, then print the maximum hourglass sum. The code goes as

```
  int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
        int result= 0;
        for(int r=0;r<=3;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<=3;c++)
            {
                int sum=arr[r][c]+arr[r][c+1]+arr[r][c+2]+arr[r+1][c+1]+arr[r+2][c]+arr[r+2][c+1]+arr[r+2][c+2];
                if(sum>result)
                {   
                    result=sum;               
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    int main()

{

    vector<vector<int>> arr(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arr[i].resize(6);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    int result = hourglassSum(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

now when I take result=0, it does not work at some test cases. but as soon as I replace result= INT_MIN, the program works fine. Since INT_MIN is just assign the minimum value that data type can hold, so why does my program not work at result=0?

Comment: Ask yourself: If you have an `int`, which can hold positive and negative numbers, is `0` the minimum number?

Comment: Can you confirm: you *may* be under the impression that the lowest value an `int` can hold is 0? That's a reasonable assumption for a beginner. Just want to see if that's the case. Try making a simple program where you just `cout` the value of `INT_MIN` to see what it is, or better yet, look at it in your debugger or follow it to its definition in your IDE.

Comment: @kiv The function does not make sense and can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: How is the function called? How is `arr` initialized? Did you try to change all `arr[r][c]` into `arr.at(r).at(c)` and check if you get an exception?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, please explain. The function should be perfectly defined if `arr` is a 6x6 matrix.

Comment: @JohnFilleau i know the value of  INT_MIN, but i want to know what difference would it make if I take result=0 or result=INT_MIN? since result is int, it can take values between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so what difference does it make what value of result i take?

Comment: What if `sum` turns out to be `-1`? What would `result` be at the end under each initial condition?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have only posted the code where my problem lies

Comment: @kiv if you don't post the code that calls this, we're free to assume that `arr` could be any dimension or no dimension. In that case, we have no idea where your actual problem lies. This function could then fail for any input that's smaller than 6x6. And give unexpected output for any dimensions larger.

Comment: @HAL9000 And if not what you will do?

Comment: thanks @JohnFilleau i have understand now where I made the mistake, i didn't considered what will happen if my end result is negative or the highest  value of an hourglass turn out to be negative, then result=0 will not make sense. I have understand it perfectly thanks.

Comment: If you ONLY EVER call this with a 6x6 vector, then please create a small `main` function that populates a 6x6 vector, calls this function, and does something with the output. It makes the intent easier for anyone coming to the question and allows us to focus on your actual problem instead of the problems you don't care about.

Comment: @JohnFilleau yeah, I will surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

With `int result= 0;`

If all `sum`  are negative, the final result would be incorrectly 0.  `if(sum>result) result=sum;` never true, so default `0` is used - which is not the maximum `sum`.

With `int result = INT_MIN;`

Any `sum` more than the current minimum value, even if all are negative, `result` is updated via `if(sum>result) result=sum;`.